# Python - " AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Tc' (Tc is one of the arguments)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import newton

R = 8.314e-5  # universal gas constant, m3-bar/K-mol
class Molecule:
"""
Store molecule info here
"""
def __init__(self, name, Tc, Pc, omega):
    """
    Pass parameters desribing molecules
    """
    #! name
    self.name = methane
    #! Critical temperature (K)
    self.Tc = -83+273
    #! Critical pressure (bar)
    self.Pc = 45.99
    #! Accentric factor
    self.omega = 0.011

def preos(molecule, T, P, plotcubic=True, printresults=True):
    Tr = T / molecule.Tc  # reduced temperature
    a = 0.457235 * R**2 * molecule.Tc**2 / molecule.Pc
    b = 0.0777961 * R * molecule.Tc / molecule.Pc
    kappa = 0.37464 + 1.54226 * molecule.omega - 0.26992 * molecule.omega**2
    alpha = (1 + kappa * (1 - np.sqrt(Tr)))**2

    A = a * alpha * P / R**2 / T**2
    B = b * P / R / T
```

When I call the function preos with the arguments I want:

```
preos("methane", 160, 10, "true", "true")
```

There's an error message: " AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Tc' " on this part:

```
def preos(molecule, T, P, plotcubic=True, printresults=True):
    Tr = T / molecule.Tc  # reduced temperature
```

And I guess it's going to have the same error for the other arguments (Pc and omega). What does this error mean?

Comment: Your code is too badly indented to deduce its function correctly - 'fraid you will have to at least fix it so it compiles without syntax errors ... the body of the `preos()` function, for example, isn't indented at all.

Comment: "having problems" is not a valid result.  What do you expect as a result from this code, and what is it actually doing?  Be exact in your description, because we're all debugging remotely, and we can't read your mind, see your screen, or have access to your data.

Comment: `"methane"` is a string, not a `Molecule`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's here:

```
def preos(molecule, T, P, plotcubic=True, printresults=True):
    Tr = T / molecule.Tc  # reduced temperature
...
preos("methane", 160, 10, "true", "true")
```

You're clearly passing "methane" into the `preos` function as a string, then trying to call .Tc on that string.  The error is saying exactly that.  This doesn't have anything to do with IPython.  In other words, you're trying to run `"methane".Tc`.

Edit: It's hard to tell what you actually want to happen, but I think you're not quite getting classes and methods.